# STM32 in emmc-slave role. DMA transfer by both edges of external clock

Tags: fpga, stm32, timer, dma, emmc

I want to implement emmc protocol in a device role with STM32 (for now I've had ST-Nucleo-F767ZI and ST-Nucleo-F429ZI dev boards). Idea is to have a **bridge** to real emmc with STM32 as an **adapter**.

STM32 (emmc mem) should sync by the external clock from the host. Here I suppose to use TIM1 in external mode 1 (TI1_ED) and capture the data from gpio by DMA.
Emmc could work in SDR and DDR modes (so, in sdr packet syncs by one edge of the clock, in ddr by both) but even with activated TI1_ED trigger source to have PeriodElapsed interrupt events I should set counter to 1 and I found that it appears only by every rising edge, **not by both**.

1. Is any **more clear/flexible way** to work with external clocks at SMT32 (then TIM1 in external mode 1)? Or configure the integrated host-emmc controller in device-role?
2. Is that possible to trigger DMA transfers (and got interrupts) by **EVERY** edge of TIM1 input?

Please note, that I've tried to find **FPGA** with IP cores SD / SDIO / MMC Host Controller, but didn't get any cheap variant (the price more than 15$, even about 25). If you can suggest something (even by architecture), it definitely will help a lot.

Comment: Which of the many variants of eMMC protocol do you intend to support? At what clock rate? For all but the slowest, it is likely impossible to do this with a microcontroller. An FPGA or CPLD is much better suited. Shopping questions are not allowed on this site, but I'd probably look at one of the ICE40 devices from Lattice due to the convenience of nonvolatile configuration memory and open-source toolchain support. It is not a challenging task for an FPGA and a low-end device will suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to reach 10 MB/s bandwidth for such a solution, so it's class E or F (or that exactly info did you ask for?). Do you think it's impossible? And I briefly checked the ICE40 and didn't found variants with MMC Host IP cores, do you mean to implement it in another way? Or it was just a vector of searching?